# Can AWS Config write to an S3 bucket with object locking enabled?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've setup AWS Config [1] to deliver configuration items to an S3 bucket. Everything works well when the S3 bucket does not have Object Locking [2] enabled. However, when that bucket does have Object Locking enabled, then AWS Config cannot create its delivery channel and errors out with the following message

> Error: Creating Delivery Channel failed: InsufficientDeliveryPolicyException: Insufficient delivery policy to s3 bucket: oss-devex-tf-module-aws-config-managed-bucket, unable to write to bucket, provided s3 key prefix is 'config-test'.

I've searched for this exception and it's usually related to permissions. While troubleshooting I've assigned AWS Config a role that has full permissions over the S3 bucket (ie, `s3:*` on both bucket and objects, which is more than what is described in the docs [3]), I have set no KMS Customer Master Key on the bucket, I've even disabled encryption at rest just for the sake of testing it.

I want to use Object Locking because of audit and compliance requirements, but I cannot find any reference to it in the AWS Config documentation.

Edit:
I have written a terraform module [4] to setup AWS Config. There are several examples in that module that work well, but only if object locking is not enabled on the S3 bucket.

[1] - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/WhatIsConfig.html

[2] - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-lock.html

[3] - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/s3-bucket-policy.html

[4] - https://gitlab.com/open-source-devex/terraform-modules/aws/config-managed-rules

Comment: Have you tried sending the output to a bucket that does _not_ have Object Locking activated? I suspect your issue is probably related to [Permissions for the Amazon S3 Bucket - AWS Config](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/s3-bucket-policy.html) rather than anything to do with Object Locking. Basically, you need to add a Bucket Policy to the destination bucket.

Comment: Yes, and it works well when Object Locking is disabled. I've edited the question with that clarification. Thanks

Comment: I'm a little confused about this. Object Locking first needs to be enabled when the bucket is created. Then, individual objects can be locked and unlocked. I'm surprised that merely activating Object Locking at the bucket level would cause a problem. It should not impact the ability to write log files. I would recommend taking another look at the [Permissions for the Amazon S3 Bucket - AWS Config](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/s3-bucket-policy.html).

Comment: Object Locking needs indeed to be enabled when the bucket is being created. When I do not enabled it (at creation time) AWS Config can create it's delivery channel and push logs to the bucket. When I do enable Object Locking when creating the bucket, then AWS Config cannot setup it's delivery channel. Thanks for the link. I did do an extensive review of the AWS documentation and found nothing that helped me with this issue. I'll add the link you posted to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer seems to be no.

I just fought with this problem for some time until I found the following documentation from AWS:

> AWS Config does not support the delivery channel to an Amazon S3 bucket where object lock is enabled.

Source: [Managing the Delivery Channel](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/manage-delivery-channel.html)

Comment: Thanks for following up. I think the docs have been updated since I've posted this question.

Answer (score 0):

To reproduce your situation, I did the following:

- Created an Amazon S3 bucket with Versioning and Object Locking activated
- Modified an existing IAM Role that was already working with AWS Config to include the new bucket
- Modified AWS Config to write to the new bucket (because I already had Config running with another bucket)

I then saw that Config created a `ConfigWritabilityCheckFile` object inside the bucket.

Some time later, an object with this path appeared:

```
AWSLogs/123456789012/Config/ap-southeast-2/2019/9/17/ConfigSnapshot/123456789012_Config_ap-southeast-2_ConfigSnapshot_20190917T224217Z_ea973cd9-25ff-4cbe-97ca-84ef150a1981.json.gz
```

So, enabling **Object Locking** does not seem to impact the ability for AWS Config to use a bucket.

You should check the IAM Role that is being used by AWS Config to confirm that it has appropriate permissions for the desired bucket.

The IAM Role I used (which I had hanging around from an existing setup, and just added the new bucket name) contained:

- `AWSConfigRole` managed policy
- `config-role_AWSConfigDeliveryPermissions_ap-southeast-2` that was probably created automatically sometime, which contained:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::stack-lock/AWSLogs/123456789012/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "s3:x-amz-acl": "bucket-owner-full-control"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

- Plus, it had a "Read Only" policy on lots of services (again, not sure of the history of why I had this!)

Comment: Thanks, did you do those things via the AWS Console? I'm asking because somethings the console does a few things in the background and I would like to port them to my terraform code. Could you please paste the role config you used?

Comment: Yes, it was done via the console. Role info added above.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this with my terraform module. I created two buckets (with and without object locking). At first enabled AWS Config to write to the bucket without object locking (with the exact same role policies as John), which works fine (`ConfigWritabilityCheckFile` gets written in the bucket). Then on a second terraform run I switch the bucket AWS Config uses to the one with object locking enabled and that produces the exact same error I had seen before (`InsufficientDeliveryPolicyException: Insufficient delivery policy to s3 bucket ...`).

Comment: I've also tried to switch the bucket of a working AWS Config setup via the AWS console and got a similar error. One that said something like:

_AWS Config doesn't have sufficient permissions to send configuration information to the specified S3 bucket. Update the role or bucket permissions and try again._

Comment: Next I tried the same setup via the AWS Console, letting it create everything (S3 bucket, roles, etc). Then I created a new bucket with object locking enabled and all other settings copied from the bucket the console had created for AWS Config. Switching buckets in AWS Config produced the same error on the console. I did notice that via the console the bucket created with object locking was on None mode (while I need at least Governance mode). I tried switching the bucket in the two modes and neither worked.